# How can I create a SOAP server in Perl?

Tags: perl, soap

I'm working with a third-party vendor who unfortunately requires that we set up a SOAP server to handle requests from them.  I'm having some trouble finding the best way to go about this.  One limitation I'm imposing is that it runs as a mod_perl2 handler.  After some searching I've found that the best way may be to use XML::Compile and its SOAP classes but I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around it.  Part of the problem is my limited understanding of SOAP and the documentation for most modules seems a bit cryptic to me.

So, can anyone give me some pointers, sample code, anything?

EDIT: we were also given a WSDL file to use, and this was not compatible with SOAP::WSDL ("unsupported global type  found in ...
Looks like a rpc/literal WSDL, which is not supported by SOAP::WSDL)

EDIT: XML::Compile::SOAP complains "RPC encoded not supported by this version" when using the WSDL with XML::Compile::WSDL11.  Can/should I not worry about the WSDL file?

Comment: FYI, I ended up with a solution that was much less clean than I wanted.. using SOAP::Parser to pull just the info I needed and used a template of the output XML filling in the one value that needed to be there.  I'm still curious if there's an easy way to make a simple SOAP server from a WSDL file that's mostly independent of the web server.

Comment: NOTE:  SOAP::Parser was a bad choice even though it works.  It's an old module that I had to install from source because it had mod_perl as a dependency. It also broke a SOAP::Lite for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a limited understanding of SOAP, starting reading about SOAP before you worry about implementing it. There are lots of [SOAP tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?q=soap+tutorial) out there. Most of the documentation probably seems cryptic to you because you don't already know SOAP.

It's not that tricky of a process. It's not that different than any other web programming when it comes to the big steps:

- You get a SOAP request, which is some XML.
- You pull apart the XML to figure out what to do.
- You put together some XML to send as a response.
- You return the response.

[XML::Compile](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Compile) will take care of most of the details for you.

Before you start writing your own server, you might consider writing a client for an existing SOAP server just to give yourself some practice.

Comment: I've actually looked at XML::Compile::SOAP but still haven't figured out how to tie it all together.  Also, I'm wanting to use the WSDL file given to us.

Comment: Don't start with the code. Start with learning about SOAP. You aren't going to understand the code until then.

Comment: I understand the basics of SOAP and the WSDL. I was hoping to get some simple examples or pointers on what modules to use and how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

I found two modules that can help you make soap server, but I never use its

[https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Compile::SOAP::Daemon](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aCompile%3a%3aSOAP%3a%3aDaemon)

[https://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP::WSDL::Server](https://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP%3a%3aWSDL%3a%3aServer)